# Correctly adding CMake project in Visual Studio into VCS

Tags: git, visual-studio, cmake, version-control

I am using CMake for the first time in my own, personal project and am trying to learn it in the process. As part of my usual workflow, I start by adding the project to git and I start that off by putting together an appropriate `.gitignore` file.

I base mine around [GitHub's gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore), so I basically add, among language-specific parts, the contents of [Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) and [CMake](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CMake.gitignore) gitignore files into my project's gitignore. Then I perform the initial commit with `git add -A && git commit`. However, I noticed some odd files getting staged. Among the expected source code files and `CMakeLists.txt`, there were extra files from the `out/` folder.

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        ...
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/.cmake/api/v1/reply/cache-v2-a86cb532f9a5f68a84b0.json
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/.cmake/api/v1/reply/cmakeFiles-v1-a5da01192952418ebc3d.json
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/.cmake/api/v1/reply/codemodel-v2-65841c1d9de9864bfa6b.json
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/.cmake/api/v1/reply/index-2021-02-26T11-53-28-0002.json
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/.cmake/api/v1/reply/target-game-Debug-b8aedf37371b69389fd6.json
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/VSInheritEnvironments.txt
        new file:   out/build/x64-Debug (default)/build.ninja
```

I couldn't find anything online about whether these files are supposed to be a part of the VCS. On one hand, they are part of the `out/build/` folder and seem like files that shouldn't be added. On the other, the CMake or VS gitignores didn't exclude these files. **Should these files be added into VCS or are GitHub's gitignore files incorrect/outdated?** Thank you for any advice or resources on this topic!

Comment: You can basically ignore everything in the directory where you set up your project (assuming you don't do an in source build which I wouldn't recommend anyways. You could also just set up the build directory completely outside the source tree which should make any special content in the `.gitignore` file unnecessary.

Comment: I looked more into the files that got staged for commit and found the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html) explaining the API (and these files). The files are requested by the VS and generated during a buildsystem generation. I tried cloning another CMake project from GitHub and opening it in VS and as expected, the files got created. This both answers my question and raises a concern - unless using VS to build the project, it might not be easily possible, because these files seem to be used to link `vcpkg` packages.